# fork a Git repo locally (copy the Git repo?)

Tags: git, git-clone, git-fork

I am having a surprisingly difficult time finding an answer to this online.

I have a local Git repo on my filesystem. There is way too much history in there. I just need to clone it with depth=5 or so, etc.

I was thinking of copying the repo locally and then pruning it (getting rid of some old stuff).

Ideally I could copy the original repo with something like:

```
git clone --depth=5 /local/path/to/repo
```

but I can't find info on the exact command to run.

I tried that last command and I got this warning:

> warning: --depth is ignored in local clones; use file:// instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the warning suggests:

```
git clone --depth=5 file:///local/path/to/repo
```

Here are the docs for this:
https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html#URLS

Thanks for edit, @Olegzandr

Comment: well it says --depth is ignored, not sure why tho

Comment: @Olegzandr From the docs, this might be the reason, `the files under .git/objects/ directory are hardlinked to save space when possible` when `--local` is used. Hard links are better than shallow clone in saving space. When hard links work, shallow clone becomes  unnecessary.